# django authentication in signup page error : 'local variable 'user' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

---

this is my signup authentication views.py def , when i add username and password and hit signup it says this error :

```
local variable 'user' referenced before assignment
```

views.py def :

```
def signup(request):

   if request.method == 'POST':
       if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
          try:
             user = User.objects.get(username = request.POST['username'])
             return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error':'try another 
             username'})
          except User.DoesNotExist:
             User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password = 
             request.POST['password1'])
             auth.login(request,user)
             return redirect('home')
   else:
       return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error':'password error'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't define `user` in the except block.

```
User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password = 
             request.POST['password1'])
```

Should be:

```
 user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password = 
             request.POST['password1'])
```